# Expected ambiguity error on clang is not present

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, clang++

This needs little explanation, but I'm expecting to get an **ambiguity error** from the following C++ code, however my compiler gives me different results that are apparently not part of the standard.

Environment:

- Windows
- Clang++ version 12.0.0
- Clang++ target = x86_64-pc-windows-msvc

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void print(int x) {
    std::cout << "INT\n";
}

void print(double d) {
    std::cout << "DOUBLE\n";
}

int main() {
    print(5l);  // 5l is type long, should cause ambiguity
}
```

output:

```
INT
```

Any idea why this is happening? My compiler is choosing the function taking an int for some reason instead of issuing an ambiguity error since it shouldn't be able to resolve the function call. Is there some conversion logic that I missed? Do I need to turn up some 'error levels' or something along those lines? Or is this a bug in the compiler? Thanks.

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/qT7M1fqon)

Comment: Is that the _exact_ program you're compiling and running?

Comment: -@NathanOliver I couldn't reproduce it aswell on godbolt, not sure what's going on.
-@DrewDormann Yes, that's the code I'm compiling and running, freshly copied and pasted.

Comment: How did you get clang on windows?  Did you compile from source?

Comment: Some background, not an answer - target `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` seems to imply that Clang is using Microsoft's stdlib implementation.  On Microsoft platforms, `long` has the same properties as `int`.  Perhaps this clang build is making `long` an alias of `int`?

Comment: @DrewDormann Your clang is working in msvc emulation mode. msvc with default compilation flags also erroneously accepts this program, but with /std:c++latest it properly rejects it.

Comment: MSVC does the same, calls `print(int)`. Unless one defines `print(long)` as well, it will call that then. That is, `int` and `long` are the same but aren’t the same.

Comment: someone helped me fix it, it turned out I had ``-fno-ms-compatibility`` to my clang compiler flags, but thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, @NathanOliver, I got it from the LLVM package

Comment: My gut tells me, the truly correct behavior should be "undefined external print(long)". Those who take standards as a bible will not agree, but in this case, I consider implicit type conversion from long to int as much of a bug as is inventing a new, obfuscating error message like "ambiguity", which obfuscates the matter, IMHO. There is no ambiguity here - just a missing function. If you look for a root cause, the very old rule `sizeof(short) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)` is to blame. C and C++ should never have kept the size of integral types open to discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out I had to add `-fno-ms-compatibility` to my clang compiler flags to switch off MSVC compatibility.